# Java Xmx parameter in Business Object SP3

Tags: java, configuration, business-objects

I need to know how to configure Xmx parameter for Java.exe in Business Object SP3

Looking in the process i found

```
D:\BusObjSP3\javasdk\jre\bin\..\..\bin\java.exe -server "-Dbobj.javaserver.home=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//java/server" -Dcom.businessobjects.pjs.common.dir=D:/BusObjSP3/common/4.0/java/lib/ "-Dcom.businessobjects.pjs.conf.file=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//java/server/conf/config.xml" "-Dorg.apache.geronimo.base.dir=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//java/server/platform" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//java/server/platform/var/temp" "-Dbusinessobjects.logs.home=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0/logging/" -DXorg.apache.geronimo.gbean.NoProxy=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false "-Dbo_cluster.classes_dir=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//classes/" "-Dbo_cluster.config_dir=D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0/win32_x86/config/" -Xms32m -Xmx256m -jar "D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//java/server/bin/boeserver.jar" -workdir "D:/BusObjSP3/BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0//java/server/work" -name ROMV08000117.AdaptiveProcessingServer -pidfile "D:\BusObjSP3\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\serverpids\ROMV08000117_ROMV08000117.AdaptiveProcessingServer.pid" -protocol default -ns ROMV08000117.dip.banca.bnl.it:6400
```

Don't know where the parameters are read... my target is to set minimum heap memory
Thanks and regards

Comment: `-Xmx` is maximum heap size, not minimum!

Answer (score 0):

Since R3 of Business Objects you set the heap size in the properties of the server inside the CMC.  Each server has a area for the Command Line Parameters and you can add parameters to them as needed.  As you already see the servers are java based so use the regular -X parameters of java to set the heap size.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update below parameter

-Xmx256m to your desiered limit i.e: -Xmx1g